# Why does maven jar project not contain it's dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar, maven-shade-plugin

I have recently been working with Spring Boot and all of the jar dependencies are packaged within the Spring Boot 'uber' jar.

I have recently made a regular jar application and none of the jars are packaged within the jar, but I am still able to execute the code within the java by calling specific classes (with main methods)

Can anyone shed some light? Any similar questions I see regarding this always speak to the shade plugin

EDIT:
I understand I didn't specify the shade plugin to create an uber jar, but could anyone explain why it's not needed for the majority of projects, and how the code is able to run if the dependencies are not there?

Comment: Because you didn't setup your POM.xml to create an 'uber' jar for your project.  That's what the shade plugin can do.  That's why the similar questions solve your problem.

Comment: But ... if you are asking why Maven doesn't create 'uber' jars by default, it is because that's not needed for the majority of Java projects.

Comment: Stephen C, could you explain WHY it's not needed?

Comment: Because most projects produce libraries.  Or WAR / EAR files.  Because many / most people who deploy / run software want the option of replacing component libraries.   But the fact is that regular JARs are just fine if you use a wrapper script or something else to manage the classpath.  And this is the way that Maven is ... and changing it now would annoy millions of developers.

Comment: So when im building the package why is it downloading all the dependencies from the maven repo if they aren't going to be used??

Comment: They are used.  They are needed for the build.  To check APIs.  They are needed for dependency / conflict analysis.   And it is easier to download them eagerly than lazily.

Comment: So it makes sense that they are needed to check APIs, etc. but how are they needed for the build if they are not being included? And why am I able to rude code in my jar (that has main classes) if the dependencies that main class uses aren't there? Sorry for having this conversation but I really do appreciate you helping me understand

Comment: "And why am I able to rude code in my jar (that has main classes) if the dependencies that main class uses aren't there?"  - Because you added the dependent JARs to the runtime classpath.  Java uses **dynamic** loading to resolve classes at runtime.  (And if you don't, then your JVM throws an exception.)

Comment: "So it makes sense that they are needed to check APIs, etc. but how are they needed for the build if they are not being included? "  -  That makes no sense.  The build's API checks are compile time.  The inclusion of the dependent JAR content in an uber JAR is to make the application run **without** messing with the runtime classpath.   Compile time != run time

Comment: (But maybe you are missing that some of the API checks are repeated at runtime by the JVM class loader ... in case something has changed.  That's one of the reasons that Java applications are slow to launch.   Trade-off.)